# UIScrollView Paging in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, paging

I am downloading the x number of images from server and show in collection view. Now I want to enabled the paging .  There are lot of tutorials on that but I am new in iOS that's why I don't know how to scroll x number of images. Here is the images of what I want 
[image: UIScollView paging]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help someone.

```
 CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
        CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);
        CGSize mxSize = CGSizeMake( [imgesArry count]*width , height-114);
        [scrlView setContentSize : mxSize];

         self.customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =YES;
        self.customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, mxSize.width, mxSize.height);


        int incX = 0 ;

        for( int i = 0; i < [imgesArry count]; i++)
        {
            UIImageView *imagView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame : CGRectMake(incX,0,width ,height-114)];
            imagView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imgesArry objectAtIndex:i]]];

            [self.customView addSubview:imagView];

            incX+= width;
        }
        [scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Get the Screen size of the screen and multiple with the array count so that we get the max width we needed and than using a for loop we add the same name of imageview we need.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder select the CollectionView click on attributes and tick the Paging Enabled.
[image]

Comment: I done that but this is not enough

Comment: what's the issue you are facing after doing this step?

Comment: Nothing is happened.. I am making an wallpaper app in which user swipe the screen to see the wallpapers but I don't know how to do custom paging of scroll view @SanketBhavsar

Answer (score 0):

please refer https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView this example and here ExampleViewController.m file in you will show normal array here you will replace array with your image array